# Rails nested attributes file uploading error - expected Array (got Rack::Utils::KeySpaceConstrainedParams)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, image-uploading, nested-attributes

I'm trying to upload images using nested attributes, but I'm getting this error:

```
Rack::Utils::ParameterTypeError - expected Array (got Rack::Utils::KeySpaceConstrainedParams) for param `project_images_attributes':
```

Whenever I edit my project to add new images. I thought if I added `child_index: ProjectImage.new.object_id`, it'll work

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :photos, ProjectImage.new, child_index: ProjectImage.new.object_id do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.label :photo, "Upload Photo" %>
  <%= ff.file_field :photo, multiple: true, name: "project[project_images_attributes][][photo]" %>
<% end %>
```

Edit:

**ProjectImage Model**

```
class ProjectImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  paperclip_opts = {
    :styles => { :large => "800x800>", :medium => "x430>", :frontpage_thumb => "130x95#", :thumb => "150x150#" }, 
    :convert_options => { :all => "-quality 75 -strip" }
  }

  has_attached_file :photo, paperclip_opts
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

**Project Model**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_images, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_images, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Comment: Please post the related models code.

Comment: @Pavan Hi! I edited with models :D

Comment: You need to change `f.simple_fields_for :photos` to `f.simple_fields_for :project_images`

Comment: @Pavan and remove the rest of the stuff? If I do that, and edit the project, it shows the number of fields depending on how many images I uploaded. so if I uploaded 2 images previously, it'll add 2 input fields.

Comment: I mean just change `:photos` to `:project_images`.

Comment: @Pavan hmmm the error seems to go away, but the images aren't saving anymore

Comment: Can you post the params generated in the question?

Comment: @Pavan actually it works! I just did a typo! HA! Thanks again!

Comment: Great! I will add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :photos, ProjectImage.new, child_index: ProjectImage.new.object_id do |ff| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :project_images, ProjectImage.new, child_index: ProjectImage.new.object_id do |ff| %>
```